Plotting Non-Numerical Categorical Charts in Grafana
Is there anyway, besides the obvious option of a table, to plot non-numeric categorical values, across time, in Grafana? I couldn't find any in-house vizualization options, nor useful plugins from the community. Please find below, what I am trying to plot in a widget in Grafana:


I doubt something like you describe exists. But on the other hand, if you'll convert label N into value N, you problem comes to simply getting alternative legend. I think such plugin exists, and even if not it should be not that difficult to create it.

@markalex I also suspected that this might be the only option. A label-to-value index mapping, and then we plot the chart with a numerical equivalent of each label. Is that what you're suggesting as well?

Yes.............

I would look at the echarts plugin. It's not a super easy solution, but nothing a LLM can't handle.

@ClémentDuveau coincidentally, that's what we're using for a make-shift solution. It's not pretty, but its something.
